# Custom behavior when clicking application icon in the Mac OS X dock

Tags: objective-c, macos, dock

I am trying to modify the default behavior when clicking the icon of a running application in the dock. By default it brings the main window of the application to the foreground.

I would like to perform a custom operation when the icon is clicked.

Any idea to achieve this?

Comment: Is this *your* application that you want to modify, or some other app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW39) in the app delegate; see the explanation there.